# Flutter - APK size doubled with no major code changes. Compression?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, compression, apk, upgrade

I recently upgraded my IDE (Android Studio) along with the flutter framework, gradle and a number of firebase dependencies. I guess none of these should make a huge difference but now when I build a release, the APK file size has doubled with no other changes to my code.

Interestingly when I run a comparison between the old and new APKs with "Analyze APK/Compare with Previous" I note the breakdown of the APK contents have changed very little in size (maybe a few MB total) but the resultant APK itself has doubled (see below...I haven't shown all contents below `res` as they are are too small to worry about ie B - kB range, and don't add up to this change.)

The old size shows contents that should add up to just over 60MB whereas the total APK size is 27.7MB (Explorer confirms the APK file size shown in the top row for both as well). Is this due to compression?!? Why might one be compressed down to 27.7MB whereas the other remains at 60.6 MB when the contents are almost the same?

[image]

Comment: I have same issue, flutter Flutter 1.22.6